# User input to select powerpoint presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I've created a macro that helps with a powerpoint presentation that needs to be updated every so often.

Rather than going into the visual basic editor and importing the macro each time I'd like to create a button in a separate presentation which will prompt the user to click on the presentation that the macro needs to work on. Similar to having an excel document with just a single button on it to work on a workbook.

A code I have that does something similar in excel (gets user to click on a sheet and activates and runs macro on sheet) is below.

```
Dim uiSheet As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
    Set uiSheet = Application.InputBox("Select a cell on the key sheet.", Type:=8).Parent
On Error GoTo 0

If uiSheet Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled"
ElseIf MsgBox("You Selected " & Chr(34) & uiSheet.Name & Chr(34) & ", Proceed?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, "Accept/Reject") = vbCancel Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled"
    Exit Sub
End If

uiSheet.Activate
```

I'd prefer to avoid creating an add-in so that the future users of the macro (which won't always be me) will have it nice and super easy and won't have to import the add-ins.

Or if someone has a better idea I'm all ears. How would YOU create a powerpoint macro that needs to run in a new presentation by a person who doesn't know how to use the developer tab?

Comment: If the code doesn't need to be updated frequently, add-in is best as you can have your custom sub be called by custom UI, be it in it's own ribbon/inside "Home". You can have a separate pptm to install and load the addin for the first time.

Comment: Hmm that may be true, I'll look into making it into an add-in, but I'd still prefer to keep it simple with a button as that's the format I've made all my other excel macros and the people using these aren't always the quickest learners

Comment: To avoid using an add-in, you'd have to put your code in a separate PPTM and train the users to open your PPTM, press Alt+F8, choose "From all open presentations" and then double click the macro you want them to run. And this might fall afoul of security restrictions that prevent them from opening the PPTM in the first place or running the macros in it. An add-in will take a little more work on your part to install on the users' computers but will give them a one-button (usually on the ribbon) way to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert an action button to the slide in the PPTM file that all users will use.
Assign it to run the macro when clicked.  You can only do this part in *Slide Show View*

On the Insert tab,  click Shapes, and then under Action Buttons (at the bottom), click the button shape that you want to add.
Click a location on the slide, and then drag to draw the shape for the button.
In the Action Settings dialog box, in the Mouse Click tab. Select run a macro

Here is some code to use Windows Explorer to have them select the presentation, then open it:

```
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False  'only allows the user to select one file
        ' Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Select the File."  'Put any text to help the user choose the correct file
        'clear filters then add pptx filter
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "PowerPoint files", "*.pptx"   ' This can be any file extension to filter the choices 
        ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
        ' user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
        ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
        fxname = .SelectedItems(1) 
      End If
   End With
 Set opres = Presentations.Open(fxname, False, False, True) 'opres is the variable for the choosen file
 opres.Windows(1).Activate  'Activates that presentation.
```

Then add the rest of your update macro.

Yes, the users will have to open the macro file, but they can run the macro to update the chosen presentation very easily.

Comment: Ooh that's some excellent code. I was thinking more on the lines of clicking an already open powerpoint though.

Comment: Then just add the action button to the presentation and the macro code to it.  The presentation has to be a pptm file. Or you could have the button open the presentation with the macro in it and run the macro.

Comment: That's not an option unfortunately otherwise I definitely would have done it in that way. The reason I'd like a separate presentation with the macro is so the original will be a macro free ppt